# Flatsome ux-theme 3.5.2 version editor mode ux builder loading issue wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I have updated all the plugins of Flatsome theme wordpress,and theme to latest version.After updation it ux builder shows loading. Front view for all user works properly ux builder not working i have increase memory limit also.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the host. I don't know what host you are using, but the one that I am using has a WAF that was forbidding the request, assuming the URL is wrong because of the execution on of the javascript when you press the update button. The error is not normally visible, even in the log errors. You need to access the console of a developer tool (for example, in Google Chrome) to find it out, that I think is what makes this one tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Flatsome.

In our case, it was **migration from one URL to another** for the WordPress site (we also went **from http to https**) that **caused the problem**.

When we for one of our WordPress pages used **Google Chrome** > right-click menu > **Inspect** and clicked on the **Console** tab, we could see messages like:

- Message 1:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://newsite.com/wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2Ftheme-editor.php%3Ffile%3Dstyle.css%26theme%3Dflatsome-child' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.oldsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/logo_blue.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

- Message 2:

logo_blue.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

We looked at the corresponding html under the Elements tab, and found that there were two images referenced for our logo (one correct and one that gave the Not Found message).

To remove the unwanted image file reference, we first tried to change the logo image file through Appearance > Configure > Header > Logo & Site Identity > Logo image, but that did not help.

Finally, we found out that the **Not Found** message was **caused by Appearance > Configure > Header > Logo & Site Identity > Logo image - Light version**. We did not have a logo specified there in the admin UI (but there had been one before), and by adding our working logo image also there, we could eliminate the Not Found message.

When we had eliminated also another similar error reported by Google Chrome > Inspect > Console (the favicon file was pointing to the old site), Flatsome and the **UX Builder started working** as it should **again**: **Instead of Loading... we could see the videos and images**.

In your case, it may not be exactly these "dangling file references" that causes the problem, but you may try the same method of identifying errors reported by Google Chrome, that when eliminated makes UX Builder work again.